# How to alter a record in a list, or data structure for rapidly adding and checking things off

Tags: f#

I'm building a web crawler in F# and I'm running into a problem with how to store the pages I've already been to and the pages that I have yet to visit.

My current implementation involves tracking state with a list of records

```
type Page = {url:Uri; visited:bool; redirects:bool}
let createCrawlLink (url: Uri) = {url=url; visited=false; redirects=false}
let initialize url = [createCrawlLink(url)]
let uriInList(data:Page list)(uri:Uri) = List.exists (fun x -> x.url.AbsoluteUri = uri.AbsoluteUri) data
let add (data:Page list) (url) = 
    let uri = new Uri(url)
    match uriInList data uri with
    | true -> data
    | false -> (createCrawlLink uri) :: data
```

Now when I pull the first item off that list and visit it I'd like to do a few things.

1. Mark the url I was directed to as visited.
2. If the url I ended up on wasn't the one I attempted to go to, mark that as visited and redirected.
3. Add all new links to the list.
4. Per page business logic
5. Recurse until everything in the list is visited.

I am getting hung up on what the functional way of altering the records visited/redirected properties are.  So far it seems like I have to find the record, make a copy with the properties I want changed, then copy the entire list into a new list with the old record removed and the new record added.

This seems like a lot of work but google isn't finding me any good data structures for this (or I don't know the words to search for).  Is there a better cleaner way?

Comment: It would be better to maintain a separate `Set` (or `HashSet`) of the visited pages rather than `visited` being a property of `Page`, otherwise lookup will become rather expensive rather quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think storing pages to visit separately from pages visited makes this simpler and more efficient whether it's functional or not.

I would store visited pages in a `Map<string, Page>`, where `string` is the URL so that you have constant time access to visited pages.

Then take queued URLs to visit from the head of a list with pattern matching and build up the results in a map.

```
type Page = { url:Uri; redirects:bool }
type PagesVisited = Map<string, Page>

let rec crawl (urisToVisit:Uri list) (visited:PagesVisited) : PagesVisited =
    match urisToVisit with
    | uri :: remainingUris ->
        if Map.containsKey (uri:Uri).AbsoluteUri visited then
            crawl remainingUris visited
        else
            let (redirects, newUris) = visit uri
            let visited' = Map.add uri.AbsoluteUri {url=uri; redirects = redirects} visited
            crawl (newUris @ urisToVisit) visited'
    | [] ->
        printfn "Finished the internet"
        visited

// Kick it off
crawl [Uri("https://stackoverflow.com")] Map.empty
```

This shows you a possible functional way of doing this loop. I've left the implementation of `visit` for you.

Note that adding new items to the front of a list is efficient. It does not create a new copy of the list in memory. So I use the list concatenation operator `@` to put what is likely to be the shorter list in front of what is likely to be longer.

Similarly, the `PagesVisited` map is not being copied on each loop, even though each instance is immutable. Structural sharing is used so that items can be added and removed while still holding references to previous versions of the map. This is much faster than a full copy.

If you care about making this fast and efficient more than keeping it functional, you would probably use the mutable collections `ResizeArray` and `Dictionary` instead.

Comment: Totally agree about the fast/efficient vs functional.  The call to load the page i'm crawling dwarfs any performance i'd get by using a mutable state.  Make it async and it'd have to be pretty awful not to totally disappear.

Answer (score 4):

You're using a list, but as ildjarn said in a comment, you should probably use a set instead. However, if you need to keep track of multiple flags per URI (has this one been visited? does this one redirect?), then you'd have to keep track of multiple sets (`visitedURIs` and `redirectingURIs`, for example).

Therefore, the data structure you probably want is the [`PersistentHashMap` from FSharpx.Collections](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/PersistentHashMap.html). It's a persistent data structure, so it's non-destructive every time you make an update in it, you get back a *new* hash map with the change, but the old hash map still exists unchanged so that any other functions that still have a reference to it will still see a consistent view of the data (this is a HUGE advantage when you start trying to parallelize your code!)

Also note that for lists, if you need to make frequent updates in the middle of an existing list, the [`PersistentVector`](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/PersistentVector.html) type (also from FSharpx.Collections) is very well-suited to that.

Comment: I've noticed that this map doesn't require comparison on the key. Are there other advantages over the one in F#? I couldn't find much information about it.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox - Actually, the `PersistentHashMap` *does* require comparison, just not very often. But if you happen to insert two different keys with the same hash into a HashMap, it will require comparison in order to distinguish the two keys from each other. As for other advantages: structural sharing means large hashmaps can be updated quite efficiently. I don't have room in comments to explain all about it, but see http://blog.higher-order.net/2009/09/08/understanding-clojures-persistenthashmap-deftwice.html for one explanation (not all that great, but maybe it'll help you).

Comment: Also, [Rich Hickey has a presentation](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey) on Clojure's data structures that includes talking about the hash-map structure (the Clojure implementation of hash-map is the data structure that the F# PersistentHashMap was based on). And it's also worth reading http://hypirion.com/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1 -- that talks about the persistent *vectors*, not hash maps, but much of the structural sharing is similar in principle between the two structures.

Comment: After reading that blog series on persistent vectors, the persistent hash map will be easier to understand. The basic idea is the same: use bit manipulation to get the trie index at each level. But where the persistent vector is bit-manipulating the index of the item being looked up, the persistent hash map is using the item's *hash code* as an "index", and at each level of the trie, the bits from that part of the hash code serve as the index into that trie node's array.

Comment: I'm probably confusing you further, so maybe reading https://michael.steindorfer.name/publications/oopsla15.pdf will help.

Comment: I'm really interested in if the specific FSharpx implementation is "better" and wondering if it can be brought into F# core. I first heard of and used persistent data structures in Clojure and I'm now a little jealous of them in F#.

Comment: RE comparison: This works fine: `let (a, b) = obj(), obj() in PersistentHashMap.ofSeq [a, 1; b, 2] |> PersistentHashMap.find b`, but this: `Map [obj(), 1]` fails to compile with "Object does not support comparison".

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I just took another look at PersistentHashMap, and it doesn't require comparison, just equality. If you insert two items with the same hash code, it ends up creating a HashCollisionNode at the bottom of the tree, which just stores all the keys and values in an `obj` array and uses `<>` to find the key you're looking for. So it doesn't require comparison, just equality. Whereas the standard `Map` type in FSharp.Core, since it's implemented as an AVL tree, *does* require comparison in its keys.

Comment: And yes, I also wish that PersistentVector and PersistentHashMap would make their way into FSharp.Core. Though I've held off on suggesting that because I'm currently working on RRBVector (*almost* finished), and there's also https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Collections/issues/49, which would be a big improvement over PersistentHashMap (HUGE improvement on iteration times). Once RRBVector and CHAMPMap are included in FSharpx.Collections, though, I'm going to be advocating for them to get into FSharp.Core.